# Office 365 and Dynamics 2011 + 2007 endpoints (discoveryservice.asmx / crmservice.asmx / ...). No way?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have developed an application using SDK 4.0 for Microsoft Dynamics. Application is big and komplex and It would take a lot of time to redevelope the whole application with SDK 2011. But since last month new users can register Dynamics crm online **only** integrated with Office 365 (available on the german version of registration site for crm online). Unfortunately Microsoft says:

> "The 2007 service endpoints are not supported in Microsoft Office 365
>   organizations. The 2007 Discovery service (CrmDiscoveryService.asmx)
>   does not return Office 365 organizations and you cannot use the
>   CrmService.asmx and MetadataService.asmx services with an Office 365
>   organization." ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334316.aspx))

How can I avoid redevelopment of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer to your question about workaround to support Office 365, but from my experience upgrade to 2011 version works okay, and it do not require redevelopment from scratch. Your application should work in CRM 2011 in the same way as in CRM 4.0, but may require minor updates, like update logic, which creates connection to CRM. Update casing o some generated properties, as crmsvcutil changes casing sinse it was in CRM 4.0 version.